# Typing any keys on an external keyboard open apps. How to revert this?

Tags: applications, external-keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I was typing like I always do using a USB keyboard with External Keyboard Helper Pro bought from Google Play. I usually type in Evernote. In a moment, I'm kind pressing more than one key a the same time - probably a Fn, Ctrl or Alt and other. I have no idea what I pressed. But since then, I *can't* type anything because the keys open other apps. If I press "e" in the keyboard, the e-mail on my tablet open, and if I press other key, other app open.

I tried to figure it out, search in the settings from my tablet and in the settings of EKH, but I don't have any shortcuts configured. I'm thinking that I press some kind of shortcut that activated other shortcuts, but I don't know how to go back to what it's like before.

How to fix/revert this?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the device?

Comment: And maybe simply power-down the keyboard (unplug, remove batteries if any) to reset it?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the site for the app you mentioned, External Keyboard Helper Pro, which has some tutorials. This section may help:

[EKH Tutorial 5 - Application shortcuts and Text strings](http://blog.apedroid.com/2012/11/ekh-tutorial-5-application-shortcuts.html)

> A nice feature in External Keyboard Helper is the possibility to add
> Application shortcuts and Text strings to keys. In this example I will
> configure Alt+G to start Gmail and Alt+M to start Maps. I will also
> make it possible to quickly write http://www.apedroid.com by just
> pressing Alt+A.
>
> First I enter the Advanced settings and choose to setup some
> Application shortcuts.

Perhaps that setting has what you need?

Comment: Trish, I tried! But I don't have any shortcuts configured in The app or in The Android settings.

Comment: I fibd this list of shortcuts. It's like I activeted somehow "search", but I don't know what it is! Android Keyboard Shortcuts: Apps

• Search + B: Open browser

• Search + C: Open contacts

• Search + E: Open e-mail

• Search + G: Open Gmail

• Search + I: Open calendar

• Search + M: Open maps

• Search + P: Open music

• Search + S: Open text messaging

• Search + Y: Open YouTube

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows key is probably broken and always seems to be pressed since Windows+E is the stock Android shortcut for email, whether you set it or not.